# How do I fix this Batch Time script?

Tags: batch-file, windows-10

I am working on a little batch program, and I am having problems with coding the time scripting, which I mean by allowing people in the program in a certain time.
The certain time is having it open at 12:00 P.M, and having it close on 11:00 P.M.
This is my script so far:

```
    @echo off
    set current_time=%time:~0,5%
    rem This piece of code below is to make it start
    if %current_time% == "12:00" goto :START
    rem this piece of code below is to make it stop
    if %current_time% == "23:00" goto :STOP
    rem and if you know batch you'll get these two
    if %current_time% lss "12:00" if %current_time% gtr "23:00" goto :STOP
    if %current_time% gtr "12:00" if %current_time% lss "23:00" goto :START
    :START

    echo The program has successfully ran.
    echo Press anything to exit now.
    pause >nul
    exit
    :STOP
    echo Sorry, but this program is closed. Come back at 12:00 P.M.
    pause >nul
    exit
```

When I try the code, it just completely ignores the time configuration and goes straight to the start procedure. Does anybody know how to fix this?
Also, PLEASE NOTE: I am using Windows 10.

Comment: Welcome as a new user to SO. I don't know what exactly you expect your code to do. As I see it all is quite normal. Batch knows only 2 variable types string and signed 32 bit integers. The quotes and the colon force a string comparison. If you want the batch to pause at some point and do another comparison you have to make a loop and to be easy on resources a delay. See `Help` and `Help Timeout`

Comment: Another hint, stacked if's are only true if both conditions are met, your line goto :stop can never be true as a number can't be less  1200 and gtr 2300. Take the other if and append and else clause. But since you leave the batch with exit in both cases the loop and delay don't make sense with your logic.

Comment: @LotPings: This phrase: _"Batch knows only 2 variable types: string and signed 32 bit integers"_ is not entirely exact. Batch environment variables can contain strings **only**. Certain commands, like `set /A` and others, _converts_ the string into a 32-bits integer before operate it, and convert the numeric result back to string before store it in a variable...

Comment: @LotPings I tried non-stacking it, but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned you can use Timeout for a delay, but there is also
[Choice](http://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) - a one key input which responds with an errorlevel 
which allows you to abort while delaying.

As aacini elaborates in his comment, variables store only strings
Set /A and If try to convert to an integer if possible.

One thing to always remember is that numbers with a leading zero
are treated as coded in octal (0x as hex.) This is important when
dealing with date/time parts month days hours mins secs.

Here is an example of a stacked if else construct

```
@echo off
:loop

Set Now=%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%
If "%Now:~0,1%" equ "0"  Set Now=%Now:~1%"
cls&Echo %Time:~0,8%  Now=%Now%

if %Now% geq 1200 (
    if %Now% leq 2300 (
        goto :START
    ) Else (
        goto :Stop
    )
) Else (
    Goto :Stop
)
Rem Could never reach here

:START
echo The program has successfully ran.
echo Press anything to exit now.
pause >nul
exit

:STOP
echo Sorry, but this program is closed. Come back at 12:00 P.M.
echo To abort, hit A
Choice /T 2 /C AN /M "Abort [A/N] " /D N >NUL
If %ErrorLevel% == 1 exit /B
Goto :loop
```

Comment: See `Help if` you wrote "Come back at 12:00" but you tested gtr 1200 This isn't greater so geq=greater or equal is the correct comparison operator.

Answer (score 1):

```
if %current_time% lss "12:00" if %current_time% gtr "23:00" goto :STOP
```

`current_time` may be eg. `12:57`. `12:57` and `"12:57"` are totally different strings. You need to quote the variable wherever you are comparing it against a quoted value,

```
if "%current_time%" lss "12:00" if "%current_time%" gtr "23:00" goto :STOP
```

**BUT** whereas this will correct the comparison, this code performs an "and" function, so you are asking "time <12:00" AND "time > 23:00" which is never going to be true. Your next statement *may* become true, but since *this* statement never becomes true, batch will simply skip to the next statement. It ignores labels - they are just position-markers.

Comment: current_time actually states the right time. If I tried to use it in **echo**, it would tell me the exact time in hour:minute format. Also, I have a question, What code were you talking about? Was it the **BUT** or something?